# Vs code takes a very long time to save a python file on mac

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

Vs code takes a very long time to save a python file, (see the two images below, it takes around 30 seconds for each in a 60-line python file). It is also laggy when writing code.

Any recommendations on how to avoid this?

My vs code specs:

```
Version: 1.69.2 (Universal)
Commit: 3b889b090b5ad5793f524b5d1d39fda662b96a2a
Date: 2022-07-18T16:12:57.074Z (2 wks ago)
Electron: 18.3.5
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160
Node.js: 16.13.2
V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 20.4.0
```

[image]

[image]

My activity monitor looks like this:

[image]

And these are my mac specs:

[image]

Comment: Try to open your file in another code editor or in IDLE, and look if it takes the same amount of time.

Comment: It's completely instantaneous in sublime

Comment: Ok, so the problem is with VS code, if you try saving files with other extensions like `.txt` or `.js` do you encounter any problems?

Comment: When I disable all extensions, this doesn't happen, it must be because of Pylance or Python extensions

Comment: Ok, disable extensions one at a time and reinstall the one you're having trouble with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this problem is probably because VS code sorts the imported packages and formats the codes first when saving the file.

You should turn off these features, then the time to save the file will be greatly reduced.

Add the following configuration to the **settings.json** to turn off these two functions:

```json
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": false
    }
```